# Regular expression greater than and less than

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I would like to match any one of these characters: `<` or `>` or `<=` or `>=` or `=`.

This one doesn't seem to work: `[/</=/>]`

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
[<>]=?|=
```

It matches `<` or `>` optionally followed by `=`, or just `=` by itself.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape any of those characters in character class. Apart from that, you need to use quantifiers, to match more than 1 repetition of those characters.

You need this:

```
[<>=]{1,2}
```

Note the quantifier, to match 2 repetitions, as required for `<=` and `>=`.

---

Also, note that this will also match - `==`, `<<`. If you strictly want to match just those 4 strings, you can use this regex:

```
[<>]=?|=
```

Using `?` after `=` makes it optional. So, first part will match - `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`. And then we add `=` using pipe.

Comment: This will also match `==`, `<<`, `=<`, etc.

Comment: @Barmar. Yeah of course. But that I have not taken so strictly. May be I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you but this one works well except it doesn't work for only < or > but it works for <= or >= or =

Comment: @saroll. That would surely work for `<` or `>`. Are you sure you are using it correctly. Apart from that, you can also try the 2nd regex.

Comment: thanks @RohitJain this one works fine [\<=>\]{1,2} adding the escape charcters

Comment: Saroll, you don't need the backslash - there's nothing to escape!

Comment: @saroll. Hey, you don't need to add escape characters. In fact `\\` is a literal backslash in a character class. It is not used to escape.

Comment: To be clear, a backslash *can* be used to escape, and can also be used to denote a shorthand character class, for example `[\]\-\w]`. It is never needed before a `<` character, whether in or out of a character class.

Comment: @RohitJain, you seem to be thinking of [POSIX bracket expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).  ColdFusion uses the JavaScript regex flavor, so ``\`` is always an escape character, inside a character class or out.

Comment: Alan, ColdFusion does not use the same regex flavour as JavaScript, it uses the Apache ORO regex engine. They are similar - in that they both lack several features (notably, lookbehinds) - but Apache ORO does have support for some features that JS's implementation lacks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using slashes (might have something with coldfusion that I'm not aware of, add them back if need be)... Your regex currently matches only one character. Try:

```
[<=>]{1,2}
```

---

If you want one regex to match only `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` and `=`, there will be a bit more to that. The REMatch() function in coldfusion will return all the matched results in an array, so it's important to specify delimiters or boundaries in one way or another, because it's like a `findall` in python, or `preg_match_all` in PHP (or flagging the global match).

The boundary I think is the simplest is the `\b`:

```
\b(?:[<>]=?|=)\b
```

[Here's a demo with `g` activated](http://www.regex101.com/r/pR5iA5).

And without these boundaries, [here's what happens](http://www.regex101.com/r/gF9hR3).

**EDIT:** Didn't realise something about the spaces. Could perhaps be fixed with this?

```
\b\s*(?:[<>]=?|=)\s*\b
```

Comment: Thank you this one only works for = or <= or >= but it doesn't work for only > or < signs

Comment: @saroll Are you sure about that? It should be matching if it's successfully matching `>=` or `<=` or `=` due to the `{1,2}`.

Comment: thanks @RohitJain this one works fine [\<=>]{1,2} adding the escape charcters

Comment: Jerry, no oddities to CF here - backslashes are *not* required (and forward slashes will match that char).

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: You raise a good point, but using `\b` isn't necessarily the right way to go about it. `\b` is for a change between `\w` and `\W` (so `1<1` matches but `1 < 1` will not). It requires something like `(?<![<>=])` and `(?![<>=])` for each side of the expression, to prevent `<<` and `==` and so on. *Unfortunately,* the first of those is not supported in CF's regex implementation, but it can still be done by using Java's regex implementation instead.

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thank you! I added an `\s?` on both sides and tested it in regex101 and seemed to be working as intended. I forgot about the spaces earlier on ^^; (Actually, `\s*` would be better I think. Changed again)

Comment: Well that then changes the match to include whitespace (so requires trimming), and still fails for things like `(x+1)>.5` which may or not occur be something the OP cares about.

Comment: @PeterBoughton Hmm, right. I guess then lookarounds are really the easier way out of this with one negative lookbehind of `(?<![<=>])` and a lookahead of `(?![<=>])`, which cannot currently be implemented to CF.

Comment: Depending on the context can potentially do `[^<>=](?:[<>]=?|=)(?![<=>])` and then (for refind) add 1 to get correct position, or (for rematch) do `.substring(1)` to remove the first character. Or, if it really needs lookbehinds then use [the library I've created](http://cfregex.net) to wrap Java regex into a set of handy CF functions. :)

Comment: @PeterBoughton Oh woa, that's actually neat! :D It would definitely be of help here I believe (especially if the strings the OP has can also begin with `[<=>]`).