# Regex that detects greater than ">" and less than "<" in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a regular expression that replaces the greater than and less than symbol on a string

i already tried

```
var regEx = "s/</</g;s/>/>/g"
var testString = "<test>"
alert(testString.replace(regEx,"*"))
```

My first time to use it please go easy on me :)
Thanks

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. How does it relate to C#?

Comment: sorry wrong title :)

Comment: Search Stackoverflow for "regex greater than less than"

Comment: you will find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495418/regular-expression-greater-than-and-less-than, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063742/greater-than-and-less-than-symbol-in-regular-expressions, only a few examples. I am sure one of them will answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regEx `|` like

```
var regEx = /<|>/g;
var testString = "<test>"
alert(testString.replace(regEx,"*"))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67pz1rsq/)

Answer (score 0):

For greater than and less than symbol.

```
var string = '<><>';
string = string.replace(/[\<\>]/g,'*');
alert(string);
```

For special characters

```
var string = '<><>';
string = string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g,'_');
alert(string);
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert the regular expression in the code before class

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

below is the code for string replace using regex

```
string input = "Dot > Not Perls";
// Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "some string", ">");
```

source :
http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace