# Splitting string with javascript using '>' character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I acknowledge that this question has probably been asked so many times before and I have tried searching all over StackOverflow for a solution, but so far nothing has worked for me.

I want to split a string but it's not working properly and spitting out individual characters as each item in an array. The string I have from my CMS uses ">" characters to separate and I am using regEx to replace the 'greater than' symbol - with a comma, which works. Sourced this solution from [Regex that detects greater than ">" and less than "<" in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141732/regex-that-detects-greater-than-and-less-than-in-a-string)

However, the arrays remain incorrectly formed, like the split() function does not even work:

```
var myString = "TEST Public Libraries Connect > News Blog > A new item"

var regEx = /<|>/g;
var myNewString = (myString.replace(regEx,","))
alert(myNewString);

myNewString.split(",");
alert(myNewString[0]);
alert(myNewString[1]);
alert(myNewString[2]);
```

I've put it up in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/2j56cva0/2/) as well, just confused as to why the split won't work properly. Is it because there is spaces in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var myNewString = myString.split(">");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j56cva0/3/

In your fiddle, you were splitting `myNewString` instead of the actual string.

Comment: Wow, really silly error I made. Thanks alot. I am awarding the correct solution to you as you made me realise that I did not need to use regEx to escape any characters, making the code less heavy.

Answer (score 1):

```
myNewString.split(",");
```

You need to assign the result of the split to something. It does not just change the string itself into an array.

```
var parts = myNewString.split(",");
```